# Single repository vs Multiple Repositories for multiple tables in Domain Driven Design

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, solid-principles

I have two tables to fetch the billing rates for standard subscribers vs premium subscribers namely StandardRate vs PremiumRates. The values are populated by the product managers.

The table access is controlled through ORMs i.e., StandardRateOrm and PremiumRateOrm. I am trying to design a Repository that accesses the ORM and retrieve rates based on certain criteria. For example, the zip code range for the users.

I am not able to concretely design whether I need two repository classes vs a single repository class.

**Option 1:**
I understand that repository hides the storage layer in the DDD and therefore only one repository called as RateRepository is sufficient to access either of the ORMs and return the results. For now, results are value objects since it's a read-only access.

**Option 2:**
However, while contemplating the SOLID principles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). It makes sense to create a Parent class called RateRepository and two child repository classes (StandardRateRepository and PremiumRateRepository) that accesses its corresponding ORM respectively since it adheres to:

1. Single Responsibility: Repositories have only one reason to
   change.
2. Open/Closed
3. Interface Segregation

With option 1, it feels like that the interface is not cleaner and also it doesn't adhere to the SOLID principles. With option 2, it feels like it's exposing the storage details in the domain layer.

Are there any known design patterns/rules for solving this?

Comment: What code uses these Value objects?

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to give a good answer without seeing the domain entity diagram.

Typically rates would be value objects as rates are typically defined by their values and not identities. Ex: any dollar bill is a dollar bill. Just because rates can be persisted it does not necessarily mean they need a repository. Repositories are usually used to work with aggregate root entities.

Even if in your domain rates are entities, a capable ORM or a custom data mapper should be used to abstract the database details (separate tables for different rates) from the object model.

Comment: Agree.  A rate is highly unlikely to be an entity - seems more like it's a value object missing from some concept in your model.  Who provides the rates?  Is it a Publisher, a Provider, etc?  Model that as an aggregate root, and then it can emit a Rate as part of its business logic.